# Cutting 4" hole on Rim Joist

Tags: hvac

Would it be advisable to cut a 4" hole on the basement rim joist to install a bathroom fan. The joist size is 8" and is supported by a basement wall.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Good question; keep 'em coming!

Answer (score 2):

Sure, you can drill a large hole in a rim joist, provided there isn’t a large post directly above the hole.

Loads will be “transferred” around the opening, whether the rim joist is parallel or perpendicular to the joists.

Comment: There are rules about **hole size and placement of holes*** in relationship to joist size that might be valuable info for future readers who are not knowledgeable about these things. It could be helpful to include that info in this answer.

Comment: @Alaskaman The reference to hole size you mention is for members in bending, (i.e.: joists, beams, etc.)